# Google drive api authenticated Http request return 403 response "The user has not granted the app xxxx read access to file xxxxxx"

Tags: python, python-2.7, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I am writing a python script trying to connect to Google drive via Drive Api v3

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.file import Storage
import os
import httplib2
import gdata.docs.service
import gdata.docs.client
import gdata.docs.data
from apiclient.discovery import build
import io
from apiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload


'''
starrt the Authintication Process for Google APi
'''

FLOW = OAuth2WebServerFlow(client_id="****************************",\
                           client_secret="************************",\
                           scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
                           redirect_uri="urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
                           user_agent="PythonFileEditor/1.0")

OUT_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'out')
CREDS_FILE = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'credentials.json')

if not os.path.exists(OUT_PATH):
    os.makedirs(OUT_PATH)

storage = Storage(CREDS_FILE)
credentials = storage.get()

if credentials is None:

    authorize_url = FLOW.step1_get_authorize_url()
    print 'Go to the following link in your browser: ' + authorize_url
    code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()
    try:
        credentials = FLOW.step2_exchange(code)
    except SystemError:
        print SystemError

    storage.put(credentials)

'''Authintication Process is Over'''

http        = httplib2.Http()
http        = credentials.authorize(http)

auth2tocken = gdata.gauth.OAuth2TokenFromCredentials(credentials)


service = build('drive', 'v3', http=http)

results = service.files().list(\
    pageSize=10,fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()

items = results.get('files', [])
if not items:
    print('No files found.')
else:
    print('Files:')
    for item in items:

        print('{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'].encode('utf8'), item['id']))
        if item.get('name')=='TestPY.txt':

            fileId=item['id']
            request = service.files().get_media(fileId=fileId)
            fh = io.FileIO(item['name'])
            downloader =MediaIoBaseDownload(fh,request)
            done = False
            while done is False:
                status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
                print "Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100)
```

this script, try to download the file named "TestPY.txt" from my google drive to my local machine, the authentication process seems fine ,as i can get the files names and IDs, but when i try to download my file, the API throw this exception

```
raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self._uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0Bw2Q7p_e5q0-SFpGUURMSWptV3M?alt=media returned "The user has not granted the app ************** read access to the file 0Bw2Q7p_e5q0-SFpGUURMSWptV3M.">
```

My scope is full privileged, so theoretically i should be able to download/upload/read/write any file!

can any one point me to the right direction?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out , i used earlier /metadata.readonly flag, and i didn't update my cridentials file accordingly.

so even my scope is now bigger, drive cant see it because its not reflected in my Json file.

Answer (score 0):

> > Go to your file location and delete `token.pickle` file.
> >
> > Rerun the file and it would work.